# Only Fixed and Random Options are Working in Illustrator CC 2015 Callipraphy Brushes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

[image: Calligraphy Brush Options]

App updated but still the same. Only fixed and random options are working in Calligraphy Brushes. I have searched but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the variation options except for "Fixed" and "Random" require a graphics tablet with a pen that is capable of detecting the relevant metrics to be connected.

You can read more about the calligraphic brush options in the Illustrator help:

- [**Illustrator Help / Calligraphic Brush Options**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/brushes.html#calligraphic_brush_options)